# Microsoft Word 2016 - Does the # sign in a path of a hyperlink cause an error?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, microsoft-word-2016

I found a problem with many hyperlinks in different word documents which used to work.
There are hyperlinks to a certain folder. The names of the folders include sometimes a # sign at the beginning of the name. Instead of going to x:\Folder1\Folder2\ #Folder3 the hyperlink opens the folder with the path x:\Folder1\Folder2.

Does the #sign affect the function of the hyperlink? It seems that the # sign stops the hyperlink right at the moment so that any other path after the # sign is not executed. Can I prevent word from interrupting the path?

Comment: Yes, a `#` has special meaning in a hyperlink, it refers to a certain position inside the targeted resource. You would need to encode `#` as `%23`. Unfortunately when I tried that, it seems that Word 2016 still doesn't like it. Also, `file:///c:/folder1/folder2/%23folder3` does not work.

Comment: Here's a duplicate (unanswered) question: https://superuser.com/questions/596414/ms-word-2013-hyperlinks-with-anchor-tags-aka-hash-tags-bookmark-tags-to-ext